# How to write to a remote domain

Tags: unix, remote-access

I have a domain www.example.com

In the domain, `www.example.com/write` directory is chmod to **777**. Now, suppose, if I want to create a new directory like `www.example.com/write/new` from `www.some-domain.com`, what should I be doing.

I know PHP, Python. Please relate the answers to this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this over HTTP? Have a look at [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV).

Answer (score 0):

Write yourself a small PHP/Python app that takes a path and a token (or user/pass) as parameter. Use the token to authenticate yourself to the script and the path as the name for the directory to create. It's probably a good idea to do some path checking (like no ".." and "/") to prevent that script from getting hijacked.

Cheers,
Fabian